# Initialising the flask-wtf form when the page loads

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Whenever the flask server is started, all the forms are initialised at that time itself. The data is interconnected between the pages, so for one form, the choices come from the database and those choices can be edited using another form on another page but after the choices are updated on that page, they remain the same for the first form. To get the new values I need to restart the server. Is there any way to refresh the values without restarting the server?

This is how the form looks like

```
class AddExpenses(Form):
reason = wtforms.StringField('reason', [validators.Required()])
amount = wtforms.IntegerField('amount', [validators.Required()])
allnames = []
allnames = getSalesman()
salesperson = wtforms.SelectField('salesperson', choices=[names for names in allnames])
submitfield = wtforms.SubmitField('Submit')
```

getSalesman() function is used to query the database and get the choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not get the choices in the view function that requires the form? For example

```
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    form = AddExpenses()
    allnames = getSalesman()
    form.salesperson.choices = [names for names in allnames]
    ...
```

You may also want to use some caching on `getSalesman()` if the database will not change often.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Can you guide me how should I cache the data as well?